# client.PutObjectAsync(request) uploading a broken image using aws lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

My image are uploading locally but when i deployed lambda its giving a broken image(Note: it is uploading image but size increases),I have added Binary Media Type in the  API Gateway ,  but still not getting right results. Interesting thing is that when i uploaded a text file it was perfect on the bucket but not images.

```
public  async Task<S3Response> ImageUpload(IFormFile file ){

 string bucket_name = "your_bucket";

 var client = new AmazonS3Client("***", "****", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

 var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

 file.CopyTo(stream);

 var request = new PutObjectRequest
 {                   

   Key = file.FileName,

   BucketName = bucket_name,  

   InputStream = stream,

   //ContentType = "application/octet-stream",

   ContentType = file.ContentType,

   CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead

 };

 response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am saving image as base64 string on s3 bucket and converting back from base64 string to my original image on the client side.If someone got a better solution kindly add in a thread.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Filebase64);
stream= new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var request = new PutObjectRequest
{

  Key=file.File_name,
  BucketName = bucket_name,
  InputStream = stream,
  ContentType = "text/plain",
  CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};
```

where Image file model class look like this :

```
public class ImageModel
{
        public String File_name { set; get; }
        public String Filebase64 { set; get; }
}
```